# How to statically compile my opencv c project to a single executable

Tags: c, opencv, executable, static-linking

As the title describes, I have a project in C using opencv.

How do I statically compile this to a single executable that I can transfer to other PCs and it will work?

The platform i am using is Windows. Programming in visual studio

Comment: Do you mean to ask, "How do I statically compile my C project on [platform] so that others do not need to install the OpenCV library before using my application?" ?

Comment: well if that works yes but i thought there might be a way to convert the project into an exectutable file, no?

Comment: as sarnold noticed, your question too general without specifying platform and toolchain you are using. Please, provide this information. It will help us to try answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can build openCV as static libs with the cmake option `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`, how you link against these libs in your program depends on your OS

Detailed [instructions for windows](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html)